# Is it bad form to ask a commentor for an accept/upvote?

Tags: discussion, comments, upvotes

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432136/nodejs-querystring-module) and the asker left a comment mentioning that it works and thanking me:

> It's work. Thanks a lot.

Is it considered bad form for me to ask for them to accept/upvote the answer?

I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194061/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-for-upvote-accept-in-an-answer-when-submitting-it) which indicates that it is not OK to ask for upvotes or an accept in the answer, but what about a direct reply to the asker in comments?

Comment: Imo: Don't ever ask someone to accept _your own_ answer.  Ask the OP to accept _a_ answer instead.

Comment: Yeah that definitely seems like a better option; thanks for the tip

Comment: If you do ask, be polite. [An example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400719/import-error-python/32400792#comment52672797_32400792)

Comment: Not that in that case, there is only 1 answer, so it's perfectly fine to ask the OP to accept your own answer.

Comment: Check to see whether the OP has upvoted/accepted anything. If they have, leave them alone. If not you could leave a comment explaining how to do it. Generally this works for accepting though, if they have the rep to upvote they've probably figured out how.

Comment: I would avoid asking someone to do something they're not actually capable of doing (upvoting an answer, when they don't have that privilege). It's kind of rude to say "You should do this", when they actually can't.

Comment: Since it is not required  that OP accepts any answer, I would say you can inform OP about the accept feature, if you see that he is new on the site or never accepted any answer. But don't force OP that he has to accept your answer.