# Is it a ok to request a checkmark from the OP?

Tags: discussion

I made an answer to this question: [SwingWorker ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260372/swingworker-progressbar/20270356#20270356) and it was the only answer (and it solved the problem) to the question. But years have passed and the asker hasn't given me credit for the answer. I want to comment on the question: *"Hey Kyle, want to mark my answer as correct?"* But, to me, it feels a little awkward. Is this a faux pax? The comment, technically, wouldn't be constructive to anyone but me. However, this *is* a site with gamification, so there's nothing deplorable with wanting more points, right?

Comment: I usually just link to http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers... Hopefully they take the hint :)

Comment: *"Hey Kyle, want to mark my answer as correct?"* is terrible phrasing. Something like *"Did my answer work for you?"* might be more appropriate.

Comment: @AniMenon The user is not a newbie, at least not anymore.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Even when he/she is not, the answer given to that question or [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305468/is-it-bad-form-to-ask-a-commentor-for-an-accept-upvote) should be used.

Comment: @AniMenon The answers on the first one seem specific to new users. Your second link has no answers, perhaps you meant the linked duplicate?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara My second link is a similar question to this and was tagged as a duplicate. Don't you find any of the above tagged questions to be a duplicate of this question?

Comment: @AniMenon I didn't ask a question... And yes, I voted for one of those dupes.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara good. Then I think you do agree its a duplicate.
If you don't think so then kindly answer this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I delete these on sight. They don't have any purpose here - there are only a few possible routes:

1. The asker accepts the answer; now we have obsolete comments that really don't look good to people coming in from Google; or
2. The asker does nothing, now we have comments that will never be acted on. They still don't look good to people coming in from Google.

Comment: Option 3: New users learn the system and use it correctly on future questions. Option 4: The check mark helps people coming from Google identify the answer as correct quicker. Option 5: A short comment doesn't really 'distract' anyone but deleting it might discourage people from answering more questions.