# Who keeps deleting my comment?

Tags: support, comments, accepted-answer, deleted-comments

I just gave an answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664023/button-does-nothing-due-to-viewpostime/55664080#55664080). The answer is helpful and I have received two upvotes. OP commented that my answer is helpful but they didn't accept my answer. Thus I have commented below my answer to remind OP to accept my answer since my answer is helpful to them.

But someone keeps deleting my comments (and the OP's comment). Did I fail to obey the rules here by asking the OP to accept my answer?

Comment: And this one of course: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on

Comment: As a general suggestion: if something happens on the site and content gets removed and you're not sure why, come to Meta and ask about it. Don't do it again. For comments it's not really a big deal, but for other things it could get you rate limited/banned if done too much (not saying you did it, but your 'keeps' in your title makes me think this may be a repeat behavior. You also seem to be a sensible fellow, so I'd prefer not to see you banned for trying to use the site ^^)

Comment: Related [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418169/16775594), for anyone who comes across this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hi, I'm Cody, and I deleted your comment(s) asking for your answer to be accepted.

You should not leave comments like this. At best, [they're noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321906). At worst, they can be easily perceived as bullying the asker into accepting your answer, no matter how delicately you try to phrase it and irrespective of your true intent.

The site already provides plenty of help and guidance for new users with regards to accepting answers. There's [a Help Center entry](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that explains acceptance and upvoting, as well as other just-in-time help that is provided to new users—e.g., [on their profile page listing their questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382865/suggestion-for-improvement-profile-questions-section).

Acceptance of an answer is *completely* optional. I'm not saying it was the case here, but it's reasonable for someone to ask a question and get an answer that works for them, but choose *not* to accept it as an indication that they're still hoping for a better answer. We don't want to give the impression that is not okay.

Note that I also deleted the comment from the asker thanking you for your answer. Nothing *wrong* with such comments, *per se*, but [we consider them to be unnecessary noise here on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged). A better way to say thanks is, as you already know, an upvote (and an accept, if appropriate).

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer. I would suggest you to notify the user if you have deleted their comments. If not, some of the users will feel like they are not getting respect. But now is ok :)

Comment: I've deleted around 1500 comments this past week. Combined, the moderator team has deleted around 7000 comments this past week. Nothing about this past week has been exceptional. That would be a *lot* of notifications. It's just not practical. Nor should it be necessary: when moderators delete comments, it's because they're obsolete, irrelevant, or in violation of our Code of Conduct. Too many of the latter *will* get you a notification, but otherwise, this is just part of the normal process of keeping the site clean. Nothing to worry too much about. @John

Comment: @JohnJoe There's a [FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117854/comment-deletion-notification) about giving notification when comment is deleted, however that is not implemented.

Comment: How do you feel about [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/2185093) answer as the expression of the community on this topic?

Comment: @Dan As that answer says, "It's okay. Once." There is an additional caveat: "All such comments are subject to being deleted at any time by moderators", especially after such time as they've already had a chance to be seen by the person you're intending to target.

Comment: @CodyGray: Your answer is excellent, but so is the comment from John Doe that user' might be notified when a comment is deleted. The moderator shouldn't need to do this, it would be done automatically by the system. Even a great moderator on a good day make mistakes (to err is human...). Besides, you want inexperienced users who post "Thanks" type noise to learn instead of being confused.

Answer (score 5):

> Thus I have commented below my answer to remind OP to accept my answer since my answer is helpful to them.
>
> ...
>
> Did I fail to obey the rule here by asking OP to accept my answer ?

Yes, regarding of the duplicates for your question you did. These are just unnecessary noise.

> Just because of the high reputation so the moderators here can do everything they want without inform the OP and me ?

That's not a matter handled by *high rep moderators*. Only elected site moderators (with a diamond (♦) in the name) can do this, and it's their job, when your comment is flagged as unnecessary noise.

Comment: what if I say I will delete my comment once my answer get accepted?

Comment: What essential difference should that make? OPs are already reminded frequently by the SE engine, if they don't have accepted any answers yet.

Comment: Note that, depending on the content of the comment, sufficiently many "No longer needed" comment flags will cause a comment to be deleted without a ♦ moderator having to do anything.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Ah well, I forgot that _Community♦_ counts as a site moderator ;-)