# Suggestion for improvement profile questions section

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page

[image: Questions section]

1. I saw some difference inconsistency in the questions list (profile page) where “accept-reminder” is visible (red text). The texts goes jagged.

   I think if they are aligned, it will be better.
2. Second thing is the statistics (stars, vote, answers, views) - all numbers are on top except the stars.

   Stars count on top example:
   [image: Stars improvement]

**Edit:**
Forgot to post info about the browser:
`Firefox Quantum 66.0.3 (64-bit) on Windows 10`

Comment: Re: Point 2. I think a reason why the favourites-counter is below the star is to be consistent with how they're shown on question pages (try starring this question). If we're striving for consistency in this, the question page's design might need to be altered as well. IMHO, on the question page, I rather the counter be below the star.

Comment: How about *entirely* removing the favourites-counter from the profile questions section? I'm not seeing how its beneficial on a *general* level. Normally one can judge a question from the upvotes—these correlate well with #favourites, no?

Comment: I think people still want to have the favorites feature, for the same reason people want to be able to star github repos. Even though the upvote is a measure of how much people like the question, the favorite count is a measure of how much people want to save that question to their own profile for future reference. If a given question is starred a lot, it may provide a different meaning to a viewer than the upvote. Yes, people can still bookmark a page in their browser, but that may be a bit more challenging to track.