# Ugly formatting with accept/bounty warning next to question

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

When a question has been ignored by the user long enough, this warning shows up:[image]

IMO, this is pretty bad formatting. The questions should be aligned horizontally, and I believe that the warning should either appear right above or right below the question. What do you think?

Comment: Related: [Suggestion for improvement profile questions section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382865/4642212), [Alignment issue with the accept reminder message in Activity -> Questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329878/289905).

Comment: Definitely agreed, I'd personally put it just above the question it's related to.

Comment: Other point is that red color is ignored by our perception, better to use light-blue color.

Comment: Yeah, it just seems to be a bug, IIRC, that warning used to be displayed above the question.

Comment: Maybe they intended it to be ugly so the OCD users will fix the issue (;

Comment: @Van What? Do you have some sort of evidence or citation for this claim that red colors are ignored by our perception? Based on what research I’ve seen, and my own experience, I’d say the exact opposite is true.

Comment: @CodyGray haven't you seen that they're changing all the red traffic lights to light-blue because people seem to miss the red?

Comment: @Mocha One doesn't need OCD to want to fix *that*.

Comment: I tally agree it looks ugly and annoying at this point of time.